# Mathematical Definition of Asymptotic Bound

Tags: big-o

Ok, so if f(n) = O(g(n)), does that mean that the lim(f(n)/g(n)) approaches zero as n goes to infinity? Could the limit, say, converge to 1/8?

Thanks in advance :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `f(n)=n, g(n)=2n`. Clearly, `f(n) = O(g(n))` and `g(n) = O(f(n))`. However, the limits converge to `2` resp. `0.5`. So, it does not need to approach 0 in all cases.

If we chose `f(n)=n, g(n)=8n`, then the respective limits go to `8` resp. `1/8`.

However, as a special case, we have the following: If `f(n)/g(n)` approaches 0, then we have `f(n) = o(g(n))` and (implicitly) `f(n) = O(g(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

if `f(n) = O(g(n))` it means that there exists a `c` such that `f(n) < c*g(n)` for all `n` greater then some number.

So all of these statements are true

```
 O(x^2)       = x
 O(x)         = x
 O(2^x)       = x
 O(x/(10^10)) = x
```

and thus `lim (x->inf) f(x)/g(x) < inf`

Comment: Sorry, I had flopped my `O` there, and you I meant that to be parsed as `x / (10^10)`